# Regxp to strip out everything except numbers and slashes

Tags: python, regex

Could someone write me a regular expression that would strip out everything except numbers and slashes?

For example I have the following:

```
[u'Posted by Kendra E. on 3/17/2016', u'Posted by Jasmine B. on 3/16/2016', u'Posted by Chris H. on 3/17/2016', u'Posted by Katie S. on 3/17/2016', u'Posted by Samidha K. on 3/17/2016', u'Posted by Melissa W. on 3/20/2016', u'Posted by Travis S. on 3/18/2016', u'Posted by Lilla L. on 3/16/2016']
```

And I want to make it

```
['3/17/2016', '3/16/2016', '3/17/2016'...]
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use [`dateutil` parser](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) to extract the date strings directly into datetime objects:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> l = [u'Posted by Kendra E. on 3/17/2016', u'Posted by Jasmine B. on 3/16/2016', u'Posted by Chris H. on 3/17/2016', u'Posted by Katie S. on 3/17/2016', u'Posted by Samidha K. on 3/17/2016', u'Posted by Melissa W. on 3/20/2016', u'Posted by Travis S. on 3/18/2016', u'Posted by Lilla L. on 3/16/2016']
>>> [parse(item, fuzzy=True) for item in l]
[datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 20, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 16, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: This might work, but I'll looking for the date in string format.

Comment: never mind this works, but would like to know how to do it using regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to replace the text, or simply capture everything but digits and slashes?

[This example](https://regex101.com/r/nF7gQ3/1) matches everything non-digit or slash, then it captures all digits and slashes. Then it replaces it with only the captured values.

Take a look at `code generator` on the left for the Python code for this regex pattern.

Comment: I'm looking to capture the numbers and slashes and get rid of everything else

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/nF7gQ3/2